# MVC 5 EF6 multiple records being created. Possible issue with ajax view refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, entity-framework-6

I have an MVC app used by multiple users (intranet) essentially it’s a view which is refreshed every 3 seconds via jQuery.   It displays the amount of records in a list that are queued by time added.

```
//ajax load partial view
$("#widgetPlaceHolder").load("/myController/GetPartialView");
```

It has an actionlink that when clicked will take the oldest item from the list

```
@Html.ActionLink("next item", "ViewNextItemWidget", "myController", new {@class = "modal-link btn"})
```

This action link displays a modal popup with details of the list item and writes a record to an audit log saying that item has been taken with a time stamp.

However intermittently it appears to be populating the audit log with two entries with the same timestamp (the time they were taken from the list) but with different entries (two different records in the list).

There only should be ONE item taken from the list.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, or if the problem is that two entries have the same timestamp why this is a problem. Please, explain.

Comment: OK thanks.  This happens rarely but sometime two items are being taken from the list where as only one item should be taken